# Contact form security

Tags: php, forms, security

I have a rather long contact form to deal with (owners request). I have reCAPTCHA, but don't I need security for visitors entering their personal info (name, email and phone number)? Is there an easy way to add security to existing form? The form does validate and is functional as is. Would someone be willing to help me with this. I am not fluent in PHP. Grateful for any help. Here is the relevant code:

```
<?php
require( 'recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php' );

$siteKey = 'Key.....';
$secret = 'Secret....';

$recaptcha = new\ ReCaptcha\ ReCaptcha( $secret, new\ ReCaptcha\ RequestMethod\ SocketPost() );

if ( !empty( $_POST )and isset( $_POST[ 'g-recaptcha-response' ] ) ):

    $gRecaptchaResponse = $_POST[ 'g-recaptcha-response' ]; //google captcha post data
$remoteIp = $_SERVER[ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ]; //to get user's ip

$recaptchaErrors = ''; // blank varible to store error

$resp = $recaptcha->verify( $gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp ); //method to verify captcha
if ( $resp->isSuccess() ) {
    // send mail or insert in db or do whatver you wish to
    $headers = 'From: CBS.Website';
    $emailbody = 'Name: ' . $_POST[ 'name' ] . "\n"
    . 'Company: ' . $_POST[ 'company' ] . "\n"
    . 'Email: ' . $_POST[ 'email' ] . "\n"
    . 'Phone: ' . $_POST[ 'phone' ] . "\n"
    . 'Referral: ' . $_POST[ 'referral' ] . "\n"
    . 'Stage: ' . $_POST[ 'stage' ] . "\n"
    . 'Budget Range: ' . $_POST[ 'budget' ] . "\n"
    . 'Geographic Location: ' . $_POST[ 'location' ] . "\n"
    . 'Type: ' . $_POST[ 'type' ] . "\n"
    . 'Special Considerations: ' . $_POST[ 'considerations' ] . "\n"
    . 'Project Type: ' . $_POST[ 'projectType' ] . "\n"
    . 'Square Footage: ' . $_POST[ 'sqfootage' ] . "\n"
    . 'Number of Stories: ' . $_POST[ 'stories' ] . "\n"
    . 'Schedule: ' . $_POST[ 'schedule' ] . "\n"
    . 'SF Budget: ' . $_POST[ 'sfbudget' ] . "\n"
    . 'Future Construction: ' . $_POST[ 'futureConst' ] . "\n"
    . 'Special Features: ' . $_POST[ 'features' ] . "\n"
    . 'Restrictions: ' . $_POST[ 'restrictions' ] . "\n";

    mail( 'myemail@mail.com', 'Contact Form Submission', $emailbody, $headers );
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"0; url=thankyou.php\">";

} else {
    $recaptchaErrors = $resp->getErrorCodes(); // set the error in varible
}
endif;
?>


 <script>
             function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
            if ( document.getElementById ) {
                var i, p, q, nm, test, num, min, max, errors = '',
                    args = MM_validateForm.arguments;
                for ( i = 0; i < ( args.length - 2 ); i += 3 ) {
                    test = args[ i + 2 ];
                    val = document.getElementById( args[ i ] );
                    if ( val ) {
                        nm = val.name;
                        if ( ( val = val.value ) != "" ) {
                            if ( test.indexOf( 'isEmail' ) != -1 ) {
                                p = val.indexOf( '@' );
                                if ( p < 1 || p == ( val.length - 1 ) ) errors += '- ' + nm + ' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
                            } else if ( test != 'R' ) {
                                num = parseFloat( val );
                                if ( isNaN( val ) ) errors += '- ' + nm + ' must contain a number.\n';
                                if ( test.indexOf( 'inRange' ) != -1 ) {
                                    p = test.indexOf( ':' );
                                    min = test.substring( 8, p );
                                    max = test.substring( p + 1 );
                                    if ( num < min || max < num ) errors += '- ' + nm + ' must contain a number between ' + min + ' and ' + max + '.\n';
                                }
                            }
                        } else if ( test.charAt( 0 ) == 'R' ) errors += '- ' + nm + ' is required.\n';
                    }
                }
                if ( errors ) alert( 'The following error(s) occurred:\n' + errors );
                document.MM_returnValue = ( errors == '' );
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

THE FORM:

```
 <form class="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="POST" title="Contact CBS Structures, Inc.">

                     <p>
                    <label>* Name</label> <span class="tiny-text">(first/last)</span>:
                    <input name="name" type="text" required="required" class="inputFieldsR" id="name" tabindex="1" size="50" maxlength="40"/>
                </p>
                    <p>
                    <label>* Company</label>
                    <input name="company" type="text" required="required" class="inputFieldsR" id="company" tabindex="2" value="" size="50" maxlength="40"/>
                </p>
                    <p>
                    <label>* E-mail</label>
                    <input name="email" type="text" required="required" class="inputFieldsR" id="email" tabindex="3" value="" size="50" maxlength="25"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>* Phone</label><span class="tiny-text"> (numbers only)</span>
                    <input name="phone" type="text" required="required" class="inputFieldsR" id="phone" tabindex="4" value="" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                </p>
                <label>* Please tell us who referred you to CBS Structures, Inc.</label>
                <input name="referral" type="text" required="required" class="inputFieldsR" id="referral" tabindex="16" value="" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Stage</label><span class="tiny-text"> (Planning/Proposal/Funded)</span>
                    <input name="stage" type="text" class="inputFields" id="stage" tabindex="5" value="" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>Budget Range</label>
                    <input name="budget" type="text" class="inputFields" id="budget" tabindex="6" value="" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>Geographic Location</label>
                    <input name="location" type="text" class="inputFields" id="location" tabindex="7" value="" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                </p>

                <p> <label>Type (Select one)</label>
                    <select name="type" size="1" id="type" tabindex="8">
                         <option value="Permanent" selected="selected">Permanent</option>
                        <option value="Semi-permanent">Semi-Permanent</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
            <br><br>
                    <p>
                    <label>Special Considerations</label><br>
                    <textarea name="considerations" cols="50" class="textareaFields" rows="9" maxlength="350" id="considerations" tabindex="10"></textarea>
                </p><br>

                <p class="radio">Project Type:
                </p>
                <div class="radioBtns">
                    <div class="radioColumn1">
                        <label>
           <input type="radio" name="projectType" value="Commercial" id="projectType_0" tabindex="10">
             Commercial</label>

                        <br>
                        <label>
             <input type="radio" name="projectType" value="Institutional" id="projectType_1">
             Institutional</label>

                        <br>
                        <label>
             <input type="radio" name="projectType" value="Municipal" id="projectType_2">
             Municipal</label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="radioColumn2">
                        <label>
             <input type="radio" name="projectType" value="Military Use" id="projectType_3">
             Military Use</label>

                        <br>

                        <label>
             <input type="radio" name="projectType" value="Residential" id="projectType_4">
             Residential</label>

                        <br>
                        <label>
             <input type="radio" name="projectType" value="Other" id="projectType_5">
             Other</label>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <p>
                    <label>What are the square footage requirements?</label>
                    <input name="sqFootage" type="text" class="inputFields" id="sqFootage" tabindex="11" value="" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Is the building(s) one story or multi-story?</label>
                        <input name="stories" type="text" class="inputFields" id="stories" tabindex="12" value="" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>What is your desired building schedule?</label>
                    <input name="schedule" type="text" class="inputFields" id="schedule" tabindex="13" value="" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>What is your SF budget?</label>
                    <input name="sfbudget" type="text" class="inputFields" id="sfbudget" tabindex="14" value="" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>Do you anticipate future construction or building phases on this site or region?</label>
                    <input name="future" type="text" class="inputFields" id="future" tabindex="15" value="" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>Does the site have any special features or views that need to be taken into consideration?</label><br>
                    <textarea name="features" cols="60" class="textareaFields" rows="6" maxlength="300" id="features" tabindex="16"></textarea>
                </p>
                <br>
                <p>
                    <label>Are there any specific site restrictions?</label><br>
                    <textarea name="restrictions" cols="60" class="textareaFields" rows="6" maxlength="300" id="restrictions" tabindex="17"></textarea>
                </p><br>


                <br>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcM_wkUAAAAALpmzA-yLgvqo1xLoBRnfuZXWMf_"></div>
                <br>
                <p>
                    <input style="color:#fff; font-size: 1.2em; width:120px; height: 40px; background-color: #246473" name="submit" type="submit" formmethod="POST" onClick="MM_validateForm('name','','R','company','','R','email','','RisEmail','phone','','RisNum','R','referral','R');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Submit">
                </p>   
            </form>
```

Comment: reCAPTCHA may make it harder for bots to use your form not for humans.

Comment: To reduce the risk of wrong / harmful user input you need to validate(is the data of the correct type), sanitize(is it harmful), and escape (e.g. do not allow js, prevent XSS). You could use PHP functions like `filter_var()` to validate and sanitize, but I'd recommend, if you can, use an established library to do this for you, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Where can I get info for this that I can understand? Ha. A video for this perhaps?